# input button big hover area

Tags: html, css, forms

I have simple form, it is styled in css. JSfiddle link : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tVHTg/)

```
<form action="" method="post" class="basic-grey">
    <h1>Report a problem 
    </h1>
    <label>
        <span>Your Name :</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Your Email :</span>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid Email Address" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Message :</span>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Specify The Problem"></textarea>
    </label> 
     <label>
        <span>Subject :</span><select name="selection">
        <option value="Job Inquiry">Job Inquiry</option>
        <option value="General Question">General Question</option>
        </select>
    </label>    
     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button"> 
    </label>    
</form>
```

Here is css style. Problem is that button have big hover area (on left side). I upload example on webhosting. [here you can see what i think](http://streamskuska.php5.sk/example.php) I tried `position:absolute` for button but i can not change position. `Position:relative` does not work too.

```
    .basic-grey {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        max-width: 500px;
        padding: 25px 15px 25px 10px;
        font: 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        color: #000;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;

    }
    .basic-grey h1 {
        font-size: 25px;
        padding: 0px 0px 10px 40px;
        display: block;
        border-bottom:1px solid #C9C9C9;
        margin: -10px -15px 30px -10px;;
        color: #000;
    }
    .basic-grey h1>span {
        display: block;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    .basic-grey label {
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .basic-grey label>span {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #000;
    }
    .basic-grey input[type="text"], .basic-grey input[type="email"], .basic-grey textarea, .basic-grey select {
        border: 1px solid #DADADA;
        color: #000;
        height: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        outline: 0 none;
        padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;
        width: 70%;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height:15px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    }
    .basic-grey textarea{
        padding: 5px 3px 3px 5px;
    }
    .basic-grey select {
        appearance:none;
        -webkit-appearance:none; 
        -moz-appearance: none;
        text-indent: 0.01px;
        text-overflow: '';
        width: 70%;
        height: 35px;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    .basic-grey textarea{
        height:100px;
    }
.basic-grey.button {
        opacity:0.7;
        background: #55596C;        
        padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
        color: #FFF;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #B6B6B6;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
.basic-grey.button:hover {
        opacity:0.7;
        background: #373E4D;
    }
```

Comment: It looks good in Chrome.

Comment: I have created a JSFiddle from the code you have provided that dosen't shows any problem.

Comment: Why are you putting an empty span there? There's css to do that task. Use margin-left?

Comment: try button left side .. When you click it active button. And it is my problem.

Comment: Delete that span and use margin-left for that!

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal thanks, removing span resolve problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the <label></label> that your button is enclosed in. Just enclose it in a div instead:

```
<div>
    <span>&nbsp;</span> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button"> 
</div>
```

If you want this div to look the same as the label, you can give it a css class, e.g. class="label" and assign the same CSS properties to "div.label" and "label".

Answer (score 0):

Remove **span** before input and set margin-left for input. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tVHTg/)

```
<label>
  <input style="margin-left: 110px" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button"> 
</label>
```